# Converting between Fiat (USD) to ether in solidity

Tags: solidity, ether, external-api

I have a situation where I send 1$ worth of ether to my smart contract..

Now, how do I validate the same on solidity? How do I make sure that the user is sending 1$ worth of ether at any given time.

I mean to say, how can I make sure `msg.value` in solidity is actually equal to 1$ worth of fiat from solidity.

Edit:
I do know, an oracle can be used as a data source. But is there an oracle that provides an api like poloinex.

Step 1: I call the https://poloniex.com/support/api/ and obtain ether - fiat value

Step 2: I send a transaction to a contract using the previously obtained value:
`contract.method.aPayableMethod().sendTransaction({ value: toWei('value from poloinex') })`

Step 3: In my payable function inside solidity, how do I make sure, that that the `msg.value` is always equal to 1$.

Comment: Can you provide more details? Because if the user sends 1 ether (lets say its worth 1$), then the contract will receive 1 ether and you do what ever you need to do with this.

Comment: I want to validate, if 1 ether is currently equal to 1$.

Comment: Hi there. "Price in USD" is almost meaningless IMO :-) Price according to who? Which exchange or market are you going to use for your valuation? Is that the same market that your contract's users will be using? What if the price in your chosen market changes while you're making the API/oracle call? What if the price changes while your user is waiting for their transaction to be mined?

Comment: Yes, Il be using coinbase exchange rate api. Wont these api's offer a 24hour average price?
And do you think, I should just check for msg.value and if it exists, just continue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please take a look at the [FiatContract](https://fiatcontract.com/). It is a donation driven contract that updates fiat values every hour.

Comment: But, it's too late. I ended up accepting ETH.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to use something like an [oracle](http://www.oraclize.it/) which could provide that information on-chain, but you need to trust that the oracle will return valid data at all times.

Comment: Look at the edit.